# How can I use Firebase 9.x + Flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flowtype

I'm working on a NextJS project using [Flow](https://flow.org/en/) and I'm trying to import [Firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package//firebase) latest version 9.1.3, but when I try to use it, Flow complains that cannot find the module.

```js
// Error: Cannot resolve module `firebase/app`.Flow(cannot-resolve-module)
import { initializeApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics';
```

I only found an [old solution on flow-typed](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/firebase_v5.x.x/flow_v0.104.x-/firebase_v5.x.x.js) for Firebase 5.x.x, but API has changed since then, and manually writing a [Library Definition](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/) is super time consuming.

I noticed that Firebase uses Typescript, is there a way I can import/convert to use Flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No flow types and TS types are not compatible although they achieve the same goal they are different in their typing philosophy.

Regarding firebase types, because firebase doesn't use flow, flow-typed is the correct place to retrieve them if the existed but no one has done so for firebase types for a while.

I have personally made a start in a project I started a while back but you may need to add more to suit your usecase ([firebase types in my project](https://github.com/Brianzchen/two-dew/blob/master/flow-typed/npm/firebase_vx.x.x.js)). If these suit your usecase as a base I'm happy to commit them into flow-typed but I'll just need to include some tests.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I started creating my own, but then I faced a similar problem with more libraries I wanted to use. I ended up dropping Flow in favor of TypeScript.